# Generate Email Subject based of a varying cell values

Tags: excel, vba, email, cell, intersect

I would like the email subject to be generated from Column A of the same row that is triggering the email.

So if Q5 = 30, I would like the subject to be pulled from A5 etc.

```vb
Dim xRg As Range

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
     On Error Resume Next
     If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
  Set xRg = Intersect(Range("Q2:Q6000"), Target)
     If xRg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
     If IsNumeric(Target.Value) And Target.Value = 30 Then
        Call Mail_small_Text_Outlook
     End If
End Sub

Sub Mail_small_Text_Outlook()
    Dim xOutApp As Object
    Dim xOutMail As Object
    Dim xMailBody As String
    Set xOutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set xOutMail = xOutApp.CreateItem(0)
    xMailBody = "Hi there" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
          "This is line 2"
    On Error Resume Next
    With xOutMail
      .To = "email address"
      .CC = ""
      .BCC = ""
      .Subject = "This should reference cell"
      .Body = xMailBody
      .Send   'or use .Send
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0
    Set xOutMail = Nothing
    Set xOutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the row of the cell that was changed using `Target.Row`, the address of the cell in column A of the same row using `"A" & Target.Row`, and pass this as an argument to the `Mail_small_Text_Outlook` Sub:

```
Call Mail_small_Text_Outlook(Range("A" & Target.Row).Value)
```

You then need to change the Sub definition to take the argument and use this for the subject when creating the email:

```
Sub Mail_small_Text_Outlook(mailSubject As String)

    ...

        .Subject = mailSubject

    ...
```

Comment: This is great, took me some tinkering but I got it. Thank you!